# php nested loop, how to?

Tags: php, iteration, nested-loops

Read some documentation about this, but I can't seem to get it right.

This is my database table called TabContent: 
http://www.mauricederegt.nl/dev/mahjong/tabtest2.php

Now I want to make a nested loop so the result will be like:

```
<div id="[TabId here]" class="tab_content"> 
     <ul class="columns"> 
         <li>[LayoutName here, all belonging to the TabId]</li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

Since this table has 3 TabId's this Div should be looped 3 times. But how to do so?

Edit: Code I have now:

```
<?php 
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM TabContent");
$assoc_array[tab_id] = array($row1, $row2, $row3);

foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
   echo'<div id="'.$k.'" class="tab_content">
     <ul class="columns">';
     foreach ($v as $data) {
       echo'<li>'.$data['LayoutName'].'</li>';
     }
    echo' </ul>
   </div>';
} ?>
```

Comment: You'll have to give more details, for example the complete output for what you want to achieve or some php code. Right now it seems you only need a simple for.

Answer (score 1):

first you have to seperate your data by tab id, maybe create a data structure like..

psuedo code:

```
$assoc_array[tab_id] = array($row1, $row2, $row3);
```

once you have a structure like this you can loop over very easy

```
foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
   <div id="$k" class="tab_content">
     <ul class="columns">
     foreach ($v as $data) {
       <li>$data['LayoutName']</li>
     }
     </ul>
   </div>
}
```

Comment: Hmm this gives me an error: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() I've adjusted my main topic and added what I have now.

I also have another table called Tabs (also put this table in the tabtest2.php example link) which has the TabId (same as the main table). What if I use this to get an array (1,2,3). Does that make things easier? But then, how to implement this in the foreach?

Answer (score 1):

I feel you should start with a good php tutorial.  This is a very fundamental question about php.  Maybe begin with [A Simple Tutorial](http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.php) or get yourself a good book such as [Begining Php](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430231149)

Answer (score 0):

If you can not split data on the tabid of the initial, you can use this example

```
        class HtmlUlGenerator{
    private $_layoutNames=array();
    public function addLayoutName($layoutName){
        $this->_layoutNames[]=$layoutName;
    }
    public function __toString(){
     $retStr="<ul class=\"columns\">";
     foreach ($this->_layoutNames as $name){
        $retStr.="<li>$name</li>";
     }
     return $retStr."</ul>";
    }
}

class TabIdDispatcher{
    private $_uls=array();
    public function addRow($row){
        $this->getUlbyTabId($row['TabId'])->addLayoutName($row['LayoutName']);
    }
    /**
     * @return HtmlUlGenerator 
     */
    private function getUlbyTabId($TabId){
        if (!key_exists($TabId, $this->_uls))
             $this->_uls[$TabId]=new HtmlUlGenerator();
         return $this->_uls[$TabId];
    }
    public function addTable($tableRows){
        foreach ($tableRows as $row){
            $this->addRow($row);
        }
    }
    public function __toString(){
        $retStr="";
        foreach ($this->_uls as $key=>$ul){
            $retStr.="<div id=\"$key\" class=\"tab_content\"> ".$ul."</div>";
        }
        return $retStr;
    }
}
```

Use it:

```
$table=array(array("TabId"=>1, "LayoutName"=>"g"),array("TabId"=>1, "LayoutName"=>"ffg"),array("TabId"=>1, "LayoutName"=>"gfg"),
array("TabId"=>2, "LayoutName"=>"g"),array("TabId"=>2, "LayoutName"=>"ffg"),array("TabId"=>2, "LayoutName"=>"gfg"),
array("TabId"=>3, "LayoutName"=>"g"),array("TabId"=>3, "LayoutName"=>"ffg"),array("TabId"=>3, "LayoutName"=>"gfg")) ; 
$obj=new TabIdDispatcher();
$obj->addTable($table);
echo $obj;
```